# How to get "open in code editor" to work with Svelte inspector in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sveltekit, wsl-2

1. I'm developing on a Windows 11 PC. The project codebase lives inside a WSL2 Linux (Ubuntu), which I edit using VS Code's WSL plugin.
2. I'm running SvelteKit inside a Docker container as part of a multiservice stack defined with a docker compose file.
3. In development setup the SvelteKit's container is running Vite's development server; aka Dockerfile has a `CMD [ "pnpm", "dev", "--host" ]`. It exposes all the relevant ports and bind mounts in all the relevant source files so I can navigate the SvelteKit's app on my Windows web browser on localhost, I have HRM working (without polling), I can attach to the process and debug it using VS Code's debugger. Overall, a great dev experience. I even have the [Svelte inspector](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/inspector.md) enabled and its mouseover functionality works just as it would if I ran the SvelteKit locally (in the WSL distro).
4. The last missing puzzle to the ultimate developer experience is getting the "open in code editor" to work when I click on a certain element using the Svelte inspector. Every time I click somewhere using the inspector, it throws a `Could not open +page.svelte in the editor.` in the container's output. If I also prepend the **dev** script in **package.json** with `EDITOR=code` (as I must, if I want the inspector's "open in code editor" functionality to work, if I run the SvelteKit dev server directly in the WSL distro, uncontainerized), it also throws an additional line of `The editor process exited with an error: spawn code ENOENT.` each time.

## What I've also tried:

1. Since I can get "open in code editor" to work as intended if I run SvelteKit straight in the WSL distro (not containerized) (it even opens the relevant line in the already open instance of VS Code, which is awesome), I figured the inspector just makes use of the `code` CLI command, which is obviously not there inside a container, so I bind mounted the same VS Code directory to it that the WSL uses and added it properly to the container's PATH environment variable. Then the errors that the inspector inside the container would throw on click would be different, on a WSL level. Obviously, because the WSL's `code` CLI command points to some bash script (/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code) which does some voodoo and naively using the same thing inside a container, which is more isolated and a different environment, wouldn't work. After that I ran out of ideas of what else could be done. I've found no relevant resources on the web.
2. I've tried what happened if I got vim installed inside the container and changed that `EDITOR=vim`. The inspector indeed opened the relevant line in vim in the container on click inside my Windows web browser, but since the container had no stdin and stdout attached (vim even warned about it), that was pretty much a dead end.

Ideally I'd like the inspector running inside the container to behave exactly as if I was running the SvelteKit dev server straight in a WSL2 distro, which is to open the relevant line inside VS Code on click in the web browser and also to keep navigating to different parts inside the same VS Code instance rather than opening a new one each time.

How close can we get to that ideal?